# Implement kernel regression in MATLAB

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, matlab, kernel-smoothing

I have a 6784x1 vector of dependent data y and a 6784x1 vector of explanatory data x and I need to perform a nonparametric regression using the Epanechnikov kernel.

For simplicity assume the bandwidth is 3 and I only need to perform the regression at time t = 10.

So I'd like to minimize the following objective with respect to a and b:

$$\Sigma_{s=10-3}^{10+3}(y_{s+1} - a - b\cdot x_{s+1})^2\cdot k_s$$

Here $k_s = \frac{3}{4}\left(1 - (\frac{s-10}{3})^2\right)$

I tried solving this using fminsearch, unfortunately this takes a very long time and the solution varies slightly with the starting value for fminsearch.

If I know how to solve this, the next step I'm planning to take is to do this for all times t.

Comment: I believe this is usually done *via* Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares (*aka* IRLS or IWLS).